# Win API to emulate drag of a file onto a window

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop

Is there any Win API to emulate drag of a file onto a window?

Comment: That's possibly the worst tagged question I've seen in quite some time :-)

Comment: I tried making it slightly better :-)

Answer (score 2):

ooh. a toughie. There's the [IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679679(VS.85).aspx) COM interface — you're not supposed to call its methods directly, since the window-manager portion of the OS does this for you. But if you could obtain the IDropTarget interface pointer from the window in question, you could pass in an [IDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688421(VS.85).aspx) containing a reference to the file in question. It wouldn't be very easy or elegant, though.

Comment: There is no way (that I know of) to query a window for its IDropTarget interface.